# Did the Dendarii Free Mercenaries survive Miles leaving them?

Tags: vorkosigan-saga

In [Was Miles exaggerating the number of Dendarii to dissuade his captors from using his people?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202750/was-miles-exaggerating-the-number-of-dendarii-to-dissuade-his-captors-from-using), I made the bold claim that Miles believed that the Dendarii Free Mercenaries would disintegrate without him to keep them united. Before he left for the final time in *Memory*, he left them under the extremely capable leadership of Elli Quinn. In *The Vor Game*, we see that the organization was still not entirely stable, with him returning to a mutiny in progress. But that was shortly after he'd started the company, and by the time of *Memory*, he's been leading them, I think, for about a decade.

Given that subsequent books deal with the years after the retirement of Admiral Naismith, is there any evidence of whether the Dendarii Free Mercenaries survived his retirement? I suspect the answer probably is in the books, but I don't have time to reread them at the moment, so I'm going to substitute a 200 point bounty (once it lets me add one) for time.

Comment: The only time I recall Miles predicting the future of the Dendarii is at the end of Warrior's Apprentice, when Gregor says "Organizations do grow and die. Any chance of them just fading away?" and Miles says "That hope has crossed my mind, but—they looked awfully healthy when I left. Growing."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Winterfair Gifts Sgt. Taura comes to the wedding. And it is explicitly stated that she is a member of the Dendarii and still under the medical care of the Dendarii medical staff. Miles even requests that they let him know when her time is short so he can try to make it to her one lat time.

My memory is a little more hazy about Cryoburn. But I do recall Miles pondering whether calling the Dendarii in for support when he is running for safety would be useful/helpful.

Sorry for the lack of chapter/references.

Comment: I wasn't certain enough to post as an answer without finding my copy and checking, but I also recall Miles thinking about the Dendarii in _Cryoburn_.

Answer (score 5):

In Cryoburn (Chapter 17), Miles and Mark **joke** about hiring the Dendarii and agree not to. But none has any doubt that the Denadarii **could** do what they were joking about.

> Miles grimaced. “Do you remember the last time you tried that?”
>   “Vividly. Don’t you?”
>   “Patchily,” said Miles dryly.
>   Mark winced.
>   “In the event, though I’ve no doubt Admiral Quinn could do the job, I would beg you to hire a different outfit.” Just in case this wasn’t quite a joke.

So yes, the Dendarii are still active and strong under Admiral Quinn by that time.
No references to the Dendarii Mercenaries in the two last books, "Flowers of Vashnoi" and "Gentleman Jole and the Red Queen", but the former is centered around Ekaterin on Barrayar, the latter around Jole and Cordelia on Sergyar, there would be no reason to discuss the Dendarii Mercenaries (only the Denadarii **mountains** !!)

Comment: If my answer is also accepted, would I get the bounty ?

Comment: Only one answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The two existing answers talk about references to the Denadarii in *Winterfair Gifts* and in *Cryoburn*.  Between them there is also another oblique reference in *Diplomatic Immunity*.

In Chapter 18 Miles is wondering how to keep his oath to Guppy that he won't be punished for his role in the story.

> Nevertheless Miles wondered where to drop Guppy when this was all over. ... .  He could think of one other nicely distant place to deposit a person of such speckled background and erratic talents, but was it fair to do that to Admiral Quinn...?  Bel had laughed evilly at the suggestion, til it had to stop to breath.

So although this story has nothing to do with the Denadarii (and is set three years after *Memory*) it is clear that Miles and Bel both still thinks of them as a going concern.  Guppy although not even aware that his antagonist was Cetagandian has nevertheless managed to become deeply entangled with their politics.  So I suppose the Denadarii, used to avoiding the Cetagandians would be a good place to leave him.